# Gitlab CI-CD using Fastlane An error occurred while installing rake (13.0.6), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I am trying to integrate CI-CD using Fastlane all the lanes are working fine in my personal laptop but when I try to push it on my repo and after the job starts it shows the below error [image]

My .gitlab.ci.yml file is

variables:
GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

stages:

- lint
- unit_tests
- archive

before_script:

- bundle install --path vendor/bundle
- bundle exec pod install

lint:
stage: lint
script:
- fastlane lint
tags:
- ios-tag

unit_tests:
stage: unit_tests
script:
- fastlane test
tags:
- ios-tag

archive_project:
stage: archive
script:
- fastlane distribute
tags:
- ios-tag

And when I try to execute the jobs it shows me the above error

I have also removed everything written in my .bash_profile considering if rvm was causing some issue

Below is the full console output when I try to run the job on GitLab:

Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.0 (c6bb62f6)
on demo for ci-cd iQtGJP4Z
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on xxxxxxxx082...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/Mohit.Pareek/Documents/CI-CD-Demo/builds/iQtGJP4Z/0/mohit.pareek/ci-cd-demo/.git/
Checking out e699b9da as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:16
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/build_info
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bundler
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/doc
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications
Fetching rake 13.0.6
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using zeitwerk 2.5.4
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using bundler 2.3.10
Fetching jmespath 1.6.1
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.7
Fetching json 2.6.1
Fetching artifactory 3.0.15
Fetching aws-partitions 1.587.0
Fetching aws-eventstream 1.2.0
Fetching babosa 1.0.4
Using claide 1.1.0
Using fuzzy_match 2.0.4
Using nap 1.1.0
Using netrc 0.11.0
Using cocoapods-deintegrate 1.0.5
Using cocoapods-downloader 1.6.3
Fetching ffi 1.15.5
Using cocoapods-try 1.2.0
Using escape 0.0.4
Using cocoapods-search 1.0.1
Using colored2 3.1.2
Using fourflusher 2.3.1
Using nanaimo 0.3.0
Using gh_inspector 1.1.3
Using molinillo 0.8.0
Using ruby-macho 2.5.1
Fetching colored 1.2
Fetching highline 2.0.3
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.8.1
Fetching declarative 0.0.20
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching dotenv 2.7.6
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching emoji_regex 3.2.3
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching excon 0.92.3
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-em_http 1.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-excon 1.1.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching multipart-post 2.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-net_http 1.0.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-net_http_persistent 1.2.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-patron 1.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-rack 1.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching faraday-retry 1.0.3
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching fastimage 2.2.6
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching jwt 2.3.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching memoist 0.16.2
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching os 1.1.4
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching trailblazer-option 0.1.2
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching uber 0.1.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching retriable 3.1.2
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching webrick 1.7.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching google-cloud-errors 1.2.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching mini_magick 4.11.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching naturally 2.2.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching optparse 0.1.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching plist 3.6.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching rubyzip 2.3.2
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching security 0.1.3
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching terminal-notifier 2.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching unicode-display_width 1.8.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching tty-screen 0.8.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching tty-cursor 0.7.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching word_wrap 1.0.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Using rouge 2.0.7
Fetching fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution 0.3.4
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching slack-notifier 2.4.0
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Fetching xcresult 0.2.1
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Bundler::SudoNotPermittedError: Bundler requires sudo access to install at the
moment. Try installing again, granting Bundler sudo access when prompted, or
installing into a different path.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler.rb:547:in `block in sudo' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler.rb:532:in` synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler.rb:532:in `sudo' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:485:in` fetch_gem'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:165:in
`install' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in` install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in` do_install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:90:in
`call' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:71:in` call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:259:in
`install_in_parallel' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:209:in` install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:89:in
`block in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:19:in` rescue in lock'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:15:in
`lock' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in
`install' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `block in install' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/settings.rb:131:in` temporary'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:254:in
`install' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in` dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in
`dispatch' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/exe/bundle:48:in` block in <top
(required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in
`with_friendly_errors' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/exe/bundle:36:in` <top
(required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load' /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in` '
An error occurred while installing rake (13.0.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile:
xcov was resolved to 1.8.1, which depends on
fastlane was resolved to 2.205.2, which depends on
google-cloud-storage was resolved to 1.36.2, which depends on
digest-crc was resolved to 0.6.4, which depends on
rake
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
lint

Duration: 18 seconds
Finished: 20 hours ago
Timeout: 1h (from project)

Runner: #8 (iQtGJP4Z) demo for ci-cd
Tags: ios-tag

Commit e699b9da
fasfzf

Pipeline #37641 for main
lint

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the issue.
Basically, access was not given. So I just uploaded my public ssh key for that specific repository ***gitlab->your_project->settings->repository->deploy keys***

It solved my issue.
Also i will suggest to move from ***rvm*** to ***rbenv*** for managing ruby

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the runner being utilized is a `shell` runner, since you are encountering issues with installing gems (e.g. - `Bundler requires sudo access to install at the moment`).

I would recommend installing Docker, and [registering a runner using the `docker` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#macos). Then, update your [`gitlab-ci.yml` to use a Ruby docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file).

Comment: I encounter the same error when using a docker image.